# Unable to copy files from HDFS to mounted device on Local FS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, mounted-volumes

We have a mounted device on our client machine which can be accessed by both windows and Unix-environments(client machine) as a **root folder**(/nas_store).

We are able to do -get or -copyToLocal to our local home directories like /home/abhinay/, but unable to copy to /nas_store, got an error as

> `get: Operation not permitted`

Can any one suggest, Any changes has to be made in hadoop config file?

Comment: Do you have write permissions to  /nas_store for the user you are executing -get operation?

Comment: Yes, I do have permissions. I am able to execute normal unix commands like cp,mv,touch etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit of a hack but here it is:

```
hdfs dfs -cat /folder_path/* | cat > /nas_store/file
```

Comment: Thanks pele88. The concept is correct. But I tried in little better way:
hdfs dfs -cat /folder_path/* > /nas_store/file